# Larger name in resume class

Tags: cv, resume

I'm working on my CV and using the resume class. I manually made all the titles so that the first letter would be a little taller than the rest with `\hsc{}{}`. I'm wondering if there is a way to make my name bigger? I'm hoping to get the name to be at least a little larger than the first section "EDUCATION".

[image]

Here is some code:

```
\ProvidesClass{resume}[2010/07/10 v0.9 Resume class]

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements

\pagestyle{plain} % Suppress page numbers

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADINGS COMMANDS: Commands for printing name and address
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def \name#1{\def\@name{#1}} % Defines the \name command to set name
\def \@name {} % Sets \@name to empty by default

\def \addressSep {$\diamond$} % Set default address separator to a diamond
```

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.8in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{hanging}

\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}
% \address{\textit{Curriculum Vitae}}
\name{\hsc{B}{ob }\hsc{R}{oss}}% Your name

\address{~bross@art.edu \quad \\ \quad  (123)~543-8654 } % Your phone number and email
```

Edit: Added information for `\hsc`

```
    {\fontsize{15}{20}\selectfont \MakeUppercase{#1}}%
    {\fontsize{11}{20}\selectfont \MakeUppercase{#2}}%
    } % first # font size; second # baseline skip
```

Comment: Currently it is a bit difficult to answer your question. Where did you find this class? Where and how is the `\hsc` command defined? If you could provide this information it would be possible to test the solutions. However, here are some guesses: you could try putting size commands in the name, for example `\name{\Large\hsc{B}{ob}}`, or the more canonical `\name{\Large\textsc{Bob Ross}}`, or use `\title{Bob Ross}` instead of `\name`.

Comment: @Marijn thanks! I added the information above for the `\hsc`

Comment: Did you try changing the numbers for the font size in the definition of `\hsc`? Or did you try the possible solutions I mentioned in my previous comment? Did they work? Alternatively you could also try replacing `\fontsize{15}{20}\selectfont` with `\Huge` and `\fontsize{11}{20}\selectfont` with `\Large` for example, or other font size commands. However, it would (still) be easier to answer if you provide the full code of the class and of your document, or a download link for the class for example (from the original source).

Comment: @Marijn Hi! Sorry for the delay. The first comment and the suggestion of `\Large`, `\Huge` didn't resolve the problem. I just created a new macro using your suggestion to change the font! Problem solved! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new macro

```
\newcommand{\tit}[2]{%
    {\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont \MakeUppercase{#1}}%
    {\fontsize{15.5}{20}\selectfont \MakeUppercase{#2}}%
    }
```

So then the name is slightly larger than the subsection title ``Education'', but still in the same structure where the first letter is a little larger.